# Burning Fat Everywhere BUT The Chest?

Tags: weight-loss

So I’ve overheard plenty abstract conversations in my day but this one really has my gears turning. I am by no means judging the individual that asked the question, I’m merely curious of the answer since I can’t think of anything aside from *avoid direct chest exercises*, and even this may be misguided as I’m also no expert (slightly above average knowledge at best).

I pay a local trainer to guide me through my bodybuilding journey, as do many, but one of her clients is transgender and has made the brave decisions to be open about it. I happened to arrive a few minutes early, and caught the tail end of their conversation where she asked if there was a way to lose body fat everywhere but the chest to give her chest a head start prior to beginning hormone therapy. She already had goals to lose weight but wanted to retain the chest she already had instead of needing implants.

I congratulated her on her current progress (she’s already lost 80lbs, which is apparently what brought the question up) and went to the training area to begin warming up.

This made me very curious as I couldn’t think of an answer and didn’t want to be rude. My trainer runs a judgement free environment and I don’t want her to get the idea that I’m judging her other clients, just merely curious.

So is there a way to accomplish this task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: [No, you can't target fat loss](http://www.yalescientific.org/2011/04/targeted-fat-loss-myth-or-reality/).

Moreover, she shouldn't avoid chest exercises but rather focus on them: while targeted  exercises don't have any impact on whether and where she loses fat and where not, chest excercises can certainly boost chest volume via increased tone and muscle growth.